# I can't find my Settings and I can't install ubuntu-desktop

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04

after it I tried to fix some problems "as always" and install some packages, after a while I tried to open the settings but I didn't find it

I tried to uninstalling and reinstalling it and fix my broken packages but nothing works.

This messages appear every time I try to install the ubuntu-desktop:
""""""

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsnmp30 : Depends: libsensors5 (>= 1:3.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

"""""""

and this is the result I receive when I try to fix brokens or upgrades

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

If anyone knows how to fix this, please help me guys
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Manually install the dependency. Run `sudo apt install libsensors5`, then repeat the initial command. If that doesn't work, install them both together with `sudo apt install libsensors5 libsnmp30`.